# How to *actually* snap a vertex to an edge

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

How do I actually snap a vertex to an edge? I want to snap a vertex to an edge based on an x, y plane (without changing the z). However, if I do that, the vertex moves away from the edge based on where I slide my cursor on it (same goes for snapping to faces sometimes). I've tried finding info about this all over the internet and am absolutely surprised I was having trouble doing so since I would think this would be a very common issue. Thanks in advance.

Here's the video to show exactly what I mean: https://youtu.be/nIPb4pqN6k0

Answer (score 2):

- Enable Snap to Edge.
- Select vertex.
- <kbd>G</kbd> (to move)
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to temporarily activate snapping and move mouse to the edge you want to snap the vertex to.
- <kbd>LMB</kbd> to validate the snapping position.

[image]

Edited to add:

In the video you seem to be locking the movement to the X Y plane of the vertex.

The vertex now confined to its X Y plane still snaps correctly to an edge.

[image]

I tried again, this time on sloping edges, (see anim. below) with the same snap options and the vertex was snapping as expected to the edge that the mouse cursor was hovering over.

Note: I added separate blue plane to show where the vertex was expected to snap to when it was moving locked to X Y plane. <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

Edit to add: Mesh similar to Reddit model ...
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142728/discussion-on-answer-by-3fingeredfrog-how-to-actually-snap-a-vertex-to-an-edge); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.